# function returns TextIO.elem option when it should be string option

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am writing a function that takes in a filename and a list of pairs of characters of which to substitute when reading the file. I am currently getting an error on one of my helping functions.

```
prac.sml:177.5-182.12 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  string option -> string * string -> unit
  result type:  TextIO.elem option -> string * string -> unit
```

Here is the function that gives the error. I don't understand exactly what could be causing this to happen, can anybody help me see what's going wrong?

```
fun echoFile (infile)  (c) (x,y) = 
    if isSome c
      then (
        printChar (valOf c) (x,y);
        echoFile infile (TextIO.input1 infile) (x,y)
      ) else ()
```

Here is the printChar function:

```
fun printChar (c) (x,y)  = 
    if x = c
      then print y
      else print c
```

And here is the function that calls it.

```
fun fileSubst _ [] = ()
  | fileSubst inputFile ((x,y)::xs) =
    let
      val infile = TextIO.openIn inputFile
    in
      echoFile infile TextIO.input1(infile) (x,y);
      TextIO.closeIn(infile);
      fileSubst inputFile xs
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some feedback to the code you've written:

- The function `TextIO.input1` has the type *TextIO.instream → TextIO.elem option*. When you [inspect the TextIO structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/text-io.html) (e.g. by writing `open TextIO;` in an sml prompt), you will find the definition `type elem = char`. So treat the output like a *char* and not a *string*. You could use the function `str` of type *char → string*. But consider using line buffering since reading files one character at a time is expensive in terms of system calls and allocation.
- I've removed [unnecessary semicolons](http://mlton.org/StandardMLGotchas#_semicolons): The ones after `fun`, `val` and other declarations are only needed in the REPL to get immediate results. The `;` between expressions is an operator.
- I've removed unnecessary parentheses. You do need parentheses when constructing tuples (`(x,y)`) and when declaring precedence. For example, `echoFile infile (TextIO.input1 infile) (x,y)` says that `echoFile` is a function with three arguments, and the second argument is `TextIO.input1 infile`, which is itself a function applied to an argument. But you don't need a second pair of parentheses to signify function application. That is, `TextIO.input1 infile` is just as good as `TextIO.input1(infile)`, just like you don't bother to write `(42)` every time you have the number `42`.

  This means you still have a bug in `fileSubst`on this line:

  ```
  echoFile infile TextIO.input1(infile) (x,y)
  ```

  since this is interpreted as `echoFile` having four arguments: `infile`, `TextIO.input1`, `(infile)` and `(x,y)`. It may seem that `TextIO.input1` and `(infile)` stick together because there's no space gap, but function application is recognized as the positioning of a function in front of its argument, *not* the presence of parentheses. Also, function application associates to the left, so if we're adding explicit parentheses to the line above, it becomes:

  ```
  (((echoFile infile) TextIO.input1) (infile)) (x,y)
  ```

  To overcome the left-associativity, we write:

  ```
  echoFile infile (TextIO.input1 infile) (x,y)
  ```

  which gets interpreted as (the bold parentheses are the explicit ones):

  `((echoFile infile)`**`(`**`TextIO.input1 infile`**`)`**`) (x,y)`
- It seems that your function `fileSubst` is supposed to replace every occurrence of the character `x` with the character `y`. I'd probably call this a "file map", since it resembles quite closely the library function `String.map` of type *(char → char) → string → string*. Whether you keep a list of *(x,y)* mappings or a *char → char* function is quite similar.

I'd probably write a function `fileMap` with the type *(char → char) → instream → outstream* to resemble `String.map`:

```
fun fileMap f inFile outFile =
    let fun go () =
            case TextIO.inputLine inFile of
                 NONE   => ()
               | SOME s => ( TextIO.output (outFile, String.map f s) ; go () )
    in go () end
```

And then use it e.g. like:

```
fun cat () = fileMap (fn c => c) TextIO.stdIn TextIO.stdOut

fun fileSubst pairs =
    fileMap (fn c => case List.find (fn (x,y) => x = c) pairs of
                          NONE       => c
                        | SOME (x,y) => y)
```

Some thoughts on these:

- When arguments for similar functions can be either *files* or *filenames*, I'd like the distinction to be more clear in the variable name. E.g. `inputFile` vs. `infile` isn't doing it for me. I'd rather have e.g. `inFile` and `filePath`.
- Whether a function should take a file path or an *instream*, I guess, depends on how you expect you want to compose it. So a very generic function like `fileMap` might take *instream* / *outstream*, but it might just as well take file paths. If you're making both types of functions, it's probably nice to either distinguish them by name or separate them into different modules.
- You probably want to deal with arbitrary *outstream*s, not just `TextIO.stdOut`, since you're dealing with arbitrary *instream*s, too. You can always special-case standard input/output like in `cat`.
- I made an auxiliary function, `go`, inside `fileMap` to deal with the recursion. In this case, I could just as well have done without and let `fileMap` call itself directly:

  ```
  fun fileMap f inFile outFile =
      case TextIO.inputLine inFile of
           NONE => ()
         | SOME s => ( TextIO.output (outFile, String.map f s)
                     ; fileMap f inFile outFile )
  ```

  since `fileMap` doesn't accumulate any state in additional arguments. But it is often the case that recursive functions need extra arguments to keep their state, while at the same time, I don't want to pollute the function's type signature (like with your `echoFile`'s `c`). This is a major use-case for monads.

  And instead of *case-of* on `List.find`, I could've used various library functions for dealing with `NONE`/`SOME` found in `Option`:

  ```
  local
    val getOpt = Option.getOpt
    val mapOpt = Option.map
    val find = List.find
  in
    fun fileSubst pairs =
      fileMap (fn c => getOpt (mapOpt #2 (find (fn (x,y) => x = c) pairs), c))
  end
  ```

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth explanation!